# show title instead of segment controll when button pressed ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have a table view that loads different data with pressing buttons in toolbar. so what i would like to do is to hide segment controll and show title if certain button is pressed and vice versa if another is pressed.

my segment controll is named sortButton and i hide it by

```
sortButton.hidden = TRUE
```

and show it with

```
sortButton.hidden = FALSE
```

so when the button is hidden i would like to hav title in its place. any idea how to fix that.

i have tried with simple

```
self.title = @"Restavracije";
```

or

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"Restavracije";
```

but title does not appear

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *sortButton; i already have this added :)

Comment: Please use `YES` and `NO` instead of `TRUE` and `FALSE`. ;) And we need some more info and/or code on how you layout is/works, since `self.title = @"whatever";` should actually work.

Comment: actually i have not write it programatically, but i just connected iboutlet so i can hide it easyer

Comment: if i change it to weak and set nil it stays on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a minimalistic demo project for you which illustrates how to accomplish what you want.

This is the relevant code:

```
@interface HASTableViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) UISegmentedControl *sortButton;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSArray *dataSource1;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSArray *dataSource2;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSArray *dataSource3;
@end

@implementation HASTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Create the segmented control
    self.sortButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[@"First", @"Second", @"Hide me"]];
    [self.sortButton addTarget:self action:@selector(switchDataInTableView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = self.sortButton;
    self.sortButton.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
    // We set the title you want to show when the segmented control is "hidden"
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Sort Button is nil.";
    // Setup a data source
    self.dataSource1 = @[@"First", @"First", @"First", @"First", @"First", @"First", @"First", @"First", @"First", @"First", @"First"];
    // and another one
    self.dataSource2 = @[@"Second", @"Second", @"Second", @"Second", @"Second"];
    // Create a third datasource which contains both arrays
    NSMutableArray *tempDataSourceArray3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.dataSource1];
    [tempDataSourceArray3 addObjectsFromArray:self.dataSource2];
    self.dataSource3 = tempDataSourceArray3;
}

- (void)switchDataInTableView {
    // Reload the table view.
    // tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath decides which datasource to show
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    // If it is "Hide it" we hide
    if (self.sortButton.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) self.navigationItem.titleView = nil;
}

#pragma mark - UITableView Data Source Methods

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // We use the standard cell
    UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    // If "First" is selected we want the text to be taken fromt the dataSource1 array
    tableViewCell.textLabel.text = self.sortButton.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? self.dataSource1[indexPath.item] : self.sortButton.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 ? self.dataSource2[indexPath.item] : self.dataSource3[indexPath.item];
    return tableViewCell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // return number of rows
    return self.sortButton.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? self.dataSource1.count : self.sortButton.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 ? self.dataSource2.count : self.dataSource3.count;
}

@end
```

[Download it here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/50800334/Demo.zip)